# Combining data frames while web scraping using rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I have the following code

```
 library('rvest')
 library('tidyverse')
 test_url <- c('http://www.citact.org/senator-brent-waltz-r-greenwood-
 district-36',
               'http://www.citact.org/senator-ron-grooms-r-new-albany-
 district-46',
               'http://www.citact.org/representative-mike-speedy-r-
 indianapolis-district-90')
 test <- lapply(test_url, function(i){
   web <- read_html(i)
   grades <- html_nodes(web, 'td')
   test_grades <- data.frame(one = (as.data.frame(html_text(grades), two = 
 'idk')))

    first <- as.data.frame(test_grades[2:11, ])
    second <- as.data.frame(test_grades[13:22, ])

    names(test_grades) <- names(test_grades)
   testing <- data.frame(c(first, second))
 })

 test_names <- lapply(test_url, function(i){
   web <- read_html(i)
   info <- html_nodes(web, 'h3')
    text_info <- html_text(info)

   names_test_df <- data_frame(member = text_info)
   names_test_df <- separate(names_test_df, col = member, c('Useless', 
  'Info'), sep = ': ')
    names_test_df <- separate(names_test_df, col = Info, c('names', 
 'District'), sep = ',')
   names_test_df <- separate(names_test_df, col = names, c('Position', 
  'First', 'Last', 'Party')
                        , sep = ' ')
   names_test_df <- separate(names_test_df, col = Party, c('Party','District 
 Name'), sep = '-')
 })

 y <- do.call(cbind.fill, c(list(do.call(rbind, test)), do.call(rbind, 
 test_names)))
```

This works in the sense that all of the information is gathered and there is no errors, but the issue lies with my final data frame which I have called y. The data frame test and the data frame test_names are not matching up when I create y. For example, some of the grades and years from test do not match the correct candidates in test_names. Is there a way to make sure that these are corresponding correctly? I tried combining the data frames prior to looping them, but I was unsuccessful in doing this. There might be a better way, that was just my initial plan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid reshaping and binding and do.call in every second line, it makes your code hard to read and thus also hard to find the bug.. I went ahead and decided to make it a bit simpler.

```
person_xpath <- "//h1[contains(@class, 'title gutter')]"

url_tables <- lapply(test_url, function(x){
  # Scraping the information (note, connecting to URL once)
  page           <- read_html(x) 
  vote_outcome   <- t(html_table(page)[[1]])
  personal_info  <- html_nodes(page, xpath = person_xpath)
  personal_info  <- html_text(personal_info)

  # Remove some useless characters and split the string
  personal_info  <- gsub("\\(|\\) |,", "", personal_info)
  split_person   <- strsplit(personal_info, " ")[[1]]

  # Prepare the personal info for a cbind:
  dupe_info      <- sapply(split_person, rep, nrow(vote_outcome))
  if(ncol(dupe_info) == 7){
    dupe_info[,4] <- paste(dupe_info[,4], dupe_info[,5])
    dupe_info     <- dupe_info[,-5]
  }
  df             <- cbind(dupe_info, vote_outcome)[,-5]
  colnames(df)   <- c("Position", "First", "Last", "Party", 
                      "District", "Year", "Outcome")
  return(df)
})

url_tables[[1]]
#     Position  First   Last    Party         District Year    
# X1  "Senator" "Brent" "Waltz" "R-Greenwood" "36"     " "    
# X2  "Senator" "Brent" "Waltz" "R-Greenwood" "36"     "2008" 
# X3  "Senator" "Brent" "Waltz" "R-Greenwood" "36"     "2009" 
# X4  "Senator" "Brent" "Waltz" "R-Greenwood" "36"     "2010" 
# ..     ...      ...     ...       ...        ...       ...

# X1  "Pro-Consumer Voting Percentage"
# X2  "0%"                            
# X3  "57%"                           
# X4  "66%"                           
# ..   ...
```

Comment: This worked, thank you. Any idea where my error was? I'm sorry it isn't good coding, I am new to R and learned it solely for this purpose.

Comment: Additionally, when I ran this on all of the url's I received this error:  Error in UseMethod("read_xml") : 
  no applicable method for 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "factor". The only thing I changed in the code above was the url's

Comment: I don't know where the error was. You must have mixed up the dimensions somewhere, or maybe some empty rows in one table. Regarding the other error, I don't know where it comes from. Could it be that the webpages are not identical or so?

Comment: I found the issue, my url's were a factor vector instead of a character vector. Thank you for your help